# Fill DataGrid according to logged in user

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Hi My scenario is like if suppose employee1 had created 3 client and employee2 had created 4 client,
What i need is that employee1 logged he must see only those detail of client which he had created.
Please guide me out how to proceed , bit confused about how create a table structure and how to get filter criteria.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you already have some tables if you are authenticating users. What *specific* problem are you having relating a user to another table? Do you have a table for employees and clients yet?  That'd be a good place to start. Table structure depends on what you need, so I don't see how anyone can help without more details.

Comment: I had used a sample registration form which is bundled with visual studio 2013 IDE.Using that i had created registration form to authencate user.. Hope u got that..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a Login, so that employees can to login to your site. Otherwise, you do not know which employee created which client.

Then, you need a business logic in which employee can only retrieve his/her client.

In database, you need to create a column to keep track of who created this client record.

### Employee Table

```
EmployeeId | Username | Password
-----------+---------------------
    1      | johndoe  |  hashed
    2      | marrydoe |  hashed
```

### Role Table

```
RoleId | Name
-------+--------------
    1  | Administrator
    2  | Employee
```

### EmployeesInRoles Table

```
EmployeeId | RoleId
-----------+--------
    1      |   2 
    2      |   2
```

### Client Table

```
ClientId | EmployeeId | Some other data
---------+------------+-----------------
    1    |     1      |  ...
    2    |     1      |  ...
```

Comment: Yes I had created a db schema..but not hv any idea how to fill the value in emplyeeId column based on logged in employee...

Comment: I updated the answer. Tables are very basic. If you want a **Login feature**, you do not want to reinvent the wheel. Instead, you want to look at [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) or [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)